# Game State Implementation Using Protocol And Base Class

Tags: objective-c, macos, state-machine

From what I've read so far, it seems that Objective C does NOT have abstract classes. I'm trying to implement a game state manager that is similar to what Apple just announced in GameKit (GKState and GKStateMachine).

My solution so far involves creating a base state class called **BaseGameState** and it adheres to a protocol I've created called **GameState**. For each state that I need for gameplay, I'm going to subclass the BaseGameState class. My BaseGameState class is just there so that I can subclass it and will not really do anything, but I want my state machine to work with one type. The class that controls which state I'm in is called **GameStateMachine** and it will contain an array of objects that are subclassed from BaseGameState.

To me, this seems like a horrible solution and I'm wondering if there's a standard method for doing this outside of using GameKit classes (which I cannot currently use because I need this app to target Yosemite).

Comment: So why would you want a base class so you just have something to subclass?Just have your GameStateMachine store an array of any object conforming to your GameState protocol. (`id <GameState>`). Base classes are usually not a good design decision.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I had a feeling that using base classes were a bad idea, but I wasn't sure what to use instead. Thanks for the feedback. Can you write this as an answer so that I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a base class, especially if it doesn't provide any implementation. This also is more flexible as it gives the user the freedom to use a different base class or extend an existing class with an implementation of your protocol.

Just have your GameStateMachine store an array of any object conforming to your GameState protocol - that is `id <GameState>`.

Comment: I've created my GameStateMachine as `@property NSMutableArray<GameState> *states;`

I have a constructor:

`-(instancetype)initWithStates:(NSMutableArray*)states {
 if (self = [super init]) {
  _states = states;
 }
 return self;
}`

It's giving me an error though. I'm not exactly sure how to implement the solution you were talking about. Any ideas?